# How do I parse two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-api

I am building a website that will allow users to input their address and return their local elected officials.  I am using Google's Civic Information API to obtain my results. When the code is executed it returns a JSON file with all of the information I need. It seems to have two arrays one for "offices" and one for "officials". I'm stuck at the point where I don't understand how to relate the two array's together and assign the office to a person. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("Used my key here");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/civicinfo/v2/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }
    
      function execute() {
        var address = street.value+" "+city.value+" "+state.value+" "+zip.value;
        return gapi.client.civicinfo.representatives.representativeInfoByAddress({
          "address": address
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                    // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                    //console.log("Response", response.result); this works
                   // Here is where I assume the logic goes to loop through and assign the information to the "demo "tag
                  },
                  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
      }
      gapi.load("client");
    

    </script> 

  </head>
  <body onload="loadClient()">
    <input name="street" type="text" id="street" placeholder="Street Address">
    <input name="city" type="text" id="city" placeholder="City">
    <input name="state" type="text" id="state" placeholder="State">
    <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" placeholder="Zip">
    <button id="calculate" onclick="execute()"> Find Elected Officials
      
    </button>
    <P id-="demo">
      
    </P>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The API cant work in this example environment (it throws an error) I suggest you will focus the question with the results that the API returns.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the api documentation: https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives#resource. Under Offices, you will find the entry

```
offices[].officialIndices[]    list    List of indices in the officials array of people who presently hold this office
```

So, you can iterate over this array and fetch the corresponding officials based on these indices.

Comment: Thanks for the response I guess that is where this is a little above my knowledge. I'm not exactly sure how that would look in this instance.

Comment: I guess, it depends on how you wish to display the data. If you want to display the officials first, and show their associated offices, it will be a bit more difficult. Showing the offices, and the officials working there would be easier. Which one are you going for?

Comment: Offices first then officials. I'd really like to make it a card but right now I'm just trying to figure out how to get it to display any where other than console.

Comment: This is probably worth a separate question. You will probably want some sort of template engine for Javascript to create the actual visible layout. I could whip up something basic with jQuery.